# Can we run two Lan cards simultaneously? one for printer and another for internet?

Tags: networking, windows-xp, lan

I have one on board NIC and one extension NIC. I connected the on-board card the LAN which grants me Internet access and the extra NIC to a Xerox printer.

However I failed to use both simultaneously.

I use BSNL YMAX internet it used auto IP configure, but Xerox printer needs an IP address.  So when ever I use only one NIC it works. How can I configure both NIC and have it work as I want it to?

OS:WIN-XP service pack-2

Comment: Sounds like you want to bridge your NICs. This will allow your printer to speak to the router going through both of your XP's NICs.  Also, I agree with Hennes.. what in the world are you doing on XP SP2?!  http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/hnw_bridge_install.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use more than one network at the same time. That makes your computer with multiple cards *multihomed*.  You just have to make sure that you keep all IPs on your LAN unique so that the software knows which NIC to use.

For a 101 on networking, [see this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work).

Not asked, but XP **SP2**? 
I would never connect that to any network at all. Update that and consider not using XP at all after [the 8<sup>th</sup> of april 2014](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/products/lifecycle).